# Can I use an OAuth2 service in a unattended workflow?

Tags: oauth-2.0

The 'flow' for OAuth2, involves getting the user to say 'yes this is OK'. The token that comes back is temporary.

But I'm trying to create a unattended service. Will the refresh token always work? I get the feeling that it too is going expire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on who is implementing OAuth2. In the [description](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2#section-1.5) of the refresh token, the expiry is not discussed as part of the specification. The spec later goes on to [state](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2#section-5.2) somewhat ambiguously that a value error of `invalid_grant` can be returned if:

> The provided authorization grant (e.g. authorization code, resource
> owner credentials) or refresh token is invalid, expired, revoked, does
> not match the redirection URI used in the authorization request, or
> was issued to another client.

This would seem to imply that it is possible for a refresh token to expire.

The document also mentions that it is possible to exchange "credentials with a long-lived access token or refresh token", thus grouping them into the same expiry class.

The latest version of the spec can be found at: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2

As for the [Google](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#handlingtheresponse) specific implementation

```
Refresh tokens are valid until the user revokes access.
```

The refresh token will be valid for all time, with the only exception coming when the user revokes that permission.

For Google OAuth2, a user can revoke permission either through a [web GUI](https://accounts.google.com/IssuedAuthSubTokens) or using an OAuth [revoke endpoint](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke).

Comment: Thank you, that Google doc seems to have changed since I last looked. I will read through it again, there were some inconsistencies in it when I read it last.